# Accessing nodes in path in neo4j without apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? When trying to use

```
Unwind apoc.coll.pairsMin(nodes(p)) as pair
```

It throws

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'apoc.coll.pairsMin' (line 3, column 8 (offset: 99))
"Unwind apoc.coll.pairsMin(nodes(p)) as pair"
```

If possible I would prefer to find a solution using out of the box software

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

This snippet should work:

```
WITH NODES(p) AS ns
UNWIND [i IN RANGE(0,SIZE(ns)-2) | ns[i..i+2]] AS pair
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this work for you?

```
// find the path you are interested in
MATCH p=(:Node {name: 'start'})-[*]->(:Node {name: 'end'})

// use reduce to iterate over the relationships
// accumulate the collections of the start and endNode for each relation
RETURN REDUCE (pairs = [], rel in relationships(p) | pairs + [[startNode(rel), endNode(rel)]] ) AS pairs
```

The equivalent APOC call would look like this

```
MATCH p=(:Node {name: 'start'})-[*]->(:Node {name: 'end'})
RETURN apoc.coll.pairsMin(nodes(p)) as pairs
```